# Calling an array from one class to another

Tags: java, swing, oop

I'm trying to create a battleship game for my school project and its still getting out of hand. I'm new to Java and this is getting a personal issue.

I have six classes, and I'm trying to pass a 2d arraylist containing my boats from my main class to another class.

My Main Class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {



        Boat_Class patrol1 = new Boat_Class("PatrolBoat",2);
        Boat_Class Destroyer1 = new Boat_Class("Destroyer",3);
        Boat_Class Battleship1 = new Boat_Class("Battleship",4);
        Boat_Class Aircraftcarrier1 = new Boat_Class("AircraftCarrier",5);

        /*Boat_Class patrol2 = new Boat_Class();
        Boat_Class Destroyer2 = new Boat_Class();
        Boat_Class Battleship2 = new Boat_Class();
        Boat_Class Aircraftcarrier2 = new Boat_Class();*/

        ArrayList<Boat_Class> player1 = new ArrayList<Boat_Class>();
        player1.add(patrol1);
        player1.add(Destroyer1);
        player1.add(Battleship1);
        player1.add(Aircraftcarrier1);

        /*ArrayList<Boat_Class> player2 = new ArrayList<Boat_Class>();
        player2.add(patrol1);
        player2.add(Destroyer1);
        player2.add(Battleship1);
        player2.add(Aircraftcarrier1);*/

        Cell [][] GridCellP1 = new Cell [10][10];
        //Cell [][] GridCellP2 = new Cell [10][10];

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Battleship");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);


        North_Panel Top = new North_Panel(player1);
        frame.add(Top, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        Center_Panel Center = new Center_Panel();
        frame.add(Center, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        South_Panel South = new South_Panel();
        frame.add(South , BorderLayout.SOUTH);


         /*Cell c = new Cell ();
         c.setColIndex(-2);
         c.setRowIndex(4);
         Center.add(c);*/



    }

}
```

The Center Panel Class were I want  my arraylist to be passed through.

```
public class Center_Panel extends JPanel {



    public Center_Panel() {

        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2, 10, 10));
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(10, 10));
        panel1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);


        char c = 'A';
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
         JButton button = new JButton((c + " " +j));
         panel1.add(button);
         button.addActionListener (new ActionListener()
         {
             @Override
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            }});
         GridCellP1 [i][j] = button;
         }

         c ++;
         }

        this.add(panel1)
```

Comment: Okay, so either declare your constructor to accept a `Cell[][]` parameter to create setter method that accepts `Cell[][]` as a parameter...

Comment: *"I'm new to Java and this is getting a personal issue."* Sometimes it pays to put code like that aside for the moment, and get a good night's sleep..

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example). 2) Use a logical & consistent code formatting style!  The code indentation is intended to help people follow the program flow. 3) A single blank line of white space is *always* enough.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 4) *"The Center Panel Class.."* which is a `Center_Panel` should just be a `JPanel`.  [Prefer composition to inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Answer (score 1):

Start by declaring your `Center_Panel` so that it takes a parameter of `Cell[][]`...

```
public class Center_Panel extends JPanel {

public Center_Panel(Cell[][] cells) {
```

Then, when you construct the `Center_Panel`, pass the value to it...

```
    Cell [][] GridCellP1 = new Cell [10][10];
    //...
    Center_Panel Center = new Center_Panel(GridCellP1);
```

You will also find if you call `setVisible(true)` on the frame after you've finished building the UI, you will have less issues...

You might also want to have a read through [Model–view–controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) as it might help you make a better design ;)

Comment: I managed to pass my array list but now, I'm having this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException: javax.swing.JButton
 at Center_Panel.<init>(Center_Panel.java:37)
 at Main.main(Main.java:56)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)                                                  And both my Center Panel and South Panel are not being displayed on my GUI

Comment: line 37 is wre i'm calling my array: GridCellP1 [i][j] = button;

Comment: What does `Cell` extend from?

Comment: cell extends from the array list created before.

Comment: No it doesn't. GridCell is a 2D array of Cell, but what is Cell?

Comment: argh sorry man, my mistake. Cell is another class in my project.

Comment: Which extends from what? I think the problem is `GridCell` can't accept buttons as elements within the array...

Comment: that's the problem for sure, as my Cell class extends from a JButton. Basically my cell class extends a jbutton and it sets the column index and row index of my ships. I think I know what the problem is now :) thanks man :)